# How to add more than one item into dictionary from user input

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am new to C# and I am trying to add more than one element in the dictionary using user input. I tried different combinations, but still I can only see 1 entry when I test the program. You can find below my registration method which is a part of a 3 option menu. I am using the dictionary as a public class and created a property so I can use it in different methods. I don't know if my logic is not correct, but I would appreciate some feedback.

```cs
private static void Register()
{
    userData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //input for user to add username and password 
    string userName = "";
    string password = "";

    SystemMessage("Enter a Username :");
    userName = Console.ReadLine();

    SystemMessage("Enter a Password :");
    password = Console.ReadLine();

    //add username and password in to dictionary
    userData.Add(userName, password);

    //check that username is not the same aas the password for better security
    if (userName.Equals(password))
    {
        ErrorMesssage("Username and Password cannot be the same");
    }

    if (userData.Equals(userName))
    {
        ErrorMesssage($"Username: {userName} already exist!");
    }
    else
    {
        //get count of key/value items
        Console.WriteLine(userData.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, it looks like every call into your Register method creates a new dictionary, and stores the username/password in that dictionary. When the method is called again, that dictionary loses all data when it is set to a new dictionary.

Comment: You want some while loop before `SystemMessage("Enter a Username :")` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick approach would be to make you dictionary a static like

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> userData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

In you current implementation every time that you call the `Register` method you create a new `Dictionary` that is of course empty.

**General feedback**

1. You process your data in wrong order

   ```
       userData.Add(userName, password);


       //check that username is not the same aas the password for better security
       if (userName.Equals(password))
       {
           ErrorMesssage("Username and Password cannot be the same");

       }

       if (userData.Equals(userName))
       {
           ErrorMesssage($"Username: {userName} already exist!");

       }
   ```

You first make the validation checks (username same as password and key exists) and then add to distionary.

2. In order to check if you have an entry in your dictionary you do not use `Equal` method but `userData.ContainsKey(userName)`

So the code should look like

```
    //check that username is not the same aas the password for better security
    if (userName.Equals(password, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        ErrorMesssage("Username and Password cannot be the same");
    }
    if (userData.ContainsKey(userName))
    {
        ErrorMesssage($"Username: {userName} already exist!");
    }
    else
    {
        //get count of key/value items
        Console.WriteLine(userData.Count);
    }
    userData.Add(userName, password);
```

3. Since it is a password, even for a uni project it might be a good idea to use some hashing at least so it is not plane test before you persist it somewhere

Comment: Hi Stelios Thanks for the feedback i tried all the methods and got familiarised on what they do i was just checking why it was only taking 1 entry in the dictionary but that is because i was keep calling it in the method. Is it not more appropriate to use try catch on the exceptions? I know what you mean about the hashing but in school we haven't even learned the dictionary yet so i will think about it.

Comment: It depends. There are people using more defensive ways wrapping the endpoint into a try catch. Some other people use try catch on high risk processes like http or database calls. If you use it in a web app that you could have multiple threads I would suggest you use a ConcurrentDictionary. And use the TryAdd() method instead. This will return a false if not possible to add the value

Comment: Thanks for the tips Stelio i am experimenting with different functionality to understand how thinks work. Btw is there any build method for masking the password char on user input? Or i will need to make my own method?

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining the dictionary every time you call Register()

Redefine the userName Dictionary outside of the method, either in main() or outside of any method globally. This will sort out your issue.

Comment: Thanks Samuel that solves the problem now i need to reference the exceptions.